# Download zipped files from server with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have files in predefine locations on my web application server. It's quite easy to download one with javascript

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}
```

But I need to find way to download multiple files as a ZIP file. How to do that?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Thank you very much :) it works. I only have problem how to handle 404 on $.get

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with it. Post it up as a new question and perhaps someone who knows the library can help.